# Run a macro based on sample ID on RTD

Tags: vba, opc, rtd

I want to run the mail macro whenever cell B1 change. I need this to happen without manual intervention because B1 is changed due to incoming RTD(OPC) server data. As it stands, unless I manually update something in my sheet the macro does not run.
rang("b1") is from RTD

```vb
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sampleID As String
If Range("B1") <> sampleID Then
sampleID = Range("B1")
Call mail
End If
```

when I change b1 manually. it will call mail Marco
but when RTD change it don't workt

Comment: Which instance triggers the update of the data?

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/UTsDTe5WEl8?feature=share Like this video but no sampleid

Comment: The `Change`-event is triggered only when a cell is modified by the user (or by VBA code). You can use the `Worksheet_Calculate`-event.

Comment: Public Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sampleID As String
If Range("B1") <> sampleID Then
sampleID = Range("B1")
Call mail
End If

Comment: `Worksheet_Calculate` has no parameters. It is triggered exactly once when Excel thinks it needs to recalculate the sheet (or parts of it)

Comment: Plus note that you likely need to declare `SampleID` as global.

Comment: `Public Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range) Dim sampleID As String If Range("B1") <> sampleID Then sampleID = Range("B1") Call mail End If ` Like this? sorry  I am vba begginer

Comment: No. `Worksheet_Calculate` has no parameters: `Public Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`. And as already said, you need to declare sampleID as Global, else it will always be empty

Comment: Add another module and sampleID as Global 
```vba 
Sub Global_Variable()
  Dim sampleID As String
 sampleID = Range("B1")
End Sub``` seems to work. Thank you @FunThomas